# Django: Can't render STATIC_URL from settings in template

Tags: python, django

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

This suggests that I can use `STATIC_URL` in my template to get the value from settings.py.

Template looks like this:

```
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}stylesheets/tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen" />
```

Settings.py looks like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

When I go to the page I just get `<link href="stylesheets/tabs.css"` i.e. no STATIC_URL.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to use `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` in your `render_to_response`, for example:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or use the new shortcut [render](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

As Dave pointed out, you should check if `django.core.context_processors.static` is in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable in settings.py. As [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor) said, it`s there by default.

Comment: you may also need to add the static context processor

Comment: After punishing myself for some time I found your little comment "django.core.context_processors.static" to be the most useful thing I have heard in the past 24 hours. THANK YOU

Comment: I don't have the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable in my settings.py file, what is happening? or what should i do?

Comment: @eLRuLL Well maybe it was deleted, check the docs and create it again

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to directly use the `STATIC_URL` variable. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11688372/2736496) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683748/django-static-url-is-not-working)

Instead of

```
{{STATIC_URL}}stylesheets/tabs.css
```

use

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% static 'stylesheets/tabs.css' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, solved like this:

in settings.py
add:

```
django.template.context_processors.static
```

here:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': TEMPLATE_DIRS,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]