# Django STATIC_URL is not working

Tags: python, django, web, django-staticfiles

Django version is 1.4. I had read the `official document`, and googled my problem.

first I had followed the official document [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/) added this in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  'django.core.context_processors.debug',
  'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
  'django.core.context_processors.media',
  'django.core.context_processors.static',
  'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
  'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

In my template:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css" ...>
```

but, in my broswer is:

```
<link href="css/main.css" ...> (Just render `STATIC_URL` as empty)
```

My settings is:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

in my `views`

```
def register(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('register.html', {'errors':errors})
```

Comment: do you have the folder ``static`` in your app?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change

```
return render_to_response('register.html', 'errors':errors)
```

to

```
return render_to_response('register.html', {'errors': errors}, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: For me, I didn't have my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` set in my `settings.py` file.  This answer helped me get it working. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6267865/1913888

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Django's `render_to_response` shortcut by default uses normal template context, which does not include context processors and all their fancy and useful stuff like `STATIC_URL`. You need to use [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), which does precicely that.

This can be called by using the new [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) (available since Django 1.3):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

return render(request, 'register.html', {'errors':errors})
```

In Django 1.2 and older, you need to supply the context explicitly:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('register.html', {'errors':errors},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 6):

In Django 1.4 you should use `static` templatetag<sup>[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#template-tags)</sup>.

Try:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "css/main.css" %} ...>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but the load line is wrong, it should be: `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: @sberder, yup, you're right. `{% load static %}` is from Django 1.3. I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

dont you need this in your return statement?:

`context_instance=RequestContext(request)`

Answer (score 2):

I realize this has already been answered but I wanted to provide another answer in the event that STATIC_URL still renders as empty even when using RequestContext.

If you are running the development server remember to start the server with the *insecure* flag to have the server serve your static files:

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```