# Why aren't my images showing up after following Django's documentation on static files?

Tags: python, django

I'm having some trouble displaying images in a website I'm building. I am following the instructions in the Django [static files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/). To wit, I have:

1. Verified that my `settings.py` file contains `STATIC_URL = 'static/'`
2. Added the equivalent of the following code to my template:

```
    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```

3. Stored my images in `my_app/static/my_app/

I get no error when I navigate to the relevant page. Just an empty div where the image should be.

It seems like in the past, this problem has been solved by using `render()` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683748/django-static-url-is-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)). However, I'm using Django 4.x, as well the `render()` function.

Why aren't my images showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more requirement, and that is adding the static url settings to our `urlpatterns`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is from the section "Serving static files during development" from that same document.