# django STATIC_URL variable is empty

Tags: python, css, django, django-1.4

Pretty popular question on here...

My template is rendering, but the {{ STATIC_URL }} variable is either empty or non-existent. I am using **django 1.4**.

Using the variable in my template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}app/backbone_project/core.css">
```

Opening up the console in my browser I see that this is the URL being requested: `http://machine-name:8000/backbone/app/backbone_project/core.css` So, `STATIC_URL` is not returning anything, i.e. if I take it out of the template the URL stays the same.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/backbone_project/core.css">
```

also returns`http://machine-name:8000/backbone/app/backbone_project/core.css`.

### **EDIT**

My settings.py file did not have `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` by default so I did not think it was required. I have added it now like this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

There is an error after doing so: `Put 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in order to use the admin application.` So, I added what it suggested like this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

The end result here is the same initial problem described above.

### **EDIT 2**

I have removed `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` completely from my settings (as it was in the default implementation of the project.) This is the code of my view:

views.py (not much to see here):

```
def homepage(request):
    return render_to_response('backbone_project/index.html', {'data':'none'})
```

### **EDIT 3**

I changed my view to use `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` so that now it looks like this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext # and other imports

def homepage(request):
    return render_to_response('backbone_project/index.html', {'data':'none'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The initial problem still persists.

Comment: Do you have `django.core.context_processors.static` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ?

Comment: If you hadn't changed the setting don't do it now. The default value includes the `static` processor plus some others that you're now leaving out.

Comment: Also, could you show the code of your view?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478855/django-cant-render-static-url-from-settings-in-template?rq=1

Comment: Just use the `RequestContext` like it says in the answer

Comment: @Adrián Sorry, the request context did fix the issue. If you put that as an answer I will accept it.